# line break in email message reply button body salesforce visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, community, email, html5, line-break

I want to display the details line by line, in an email message reply link body.

When a user clicks on the link in the email message, it is automatically populating with Subject, Body values.
In that body I want to display the details line by line.

```
<apex:outputlink style="color:red" value="mailto:{!$User.email}?subject=Re: Test Subject &Body= select the send button to send email '<br>'  NOTE: Please do not modify this Email ">
                    Click here to respond for this email 
</apex:outputlink>
```

Here it is displaying as
[image]

I tried '
', '\r\n\r\n', '\n\r'.

But it didn't work for me.

I want to display it as.
[image]
Can you please provide any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code for line break "%0d%0a"

```
<apex:outputlink style="color:red" value="mailto:{!$User.email}?subject=Re: Test Subject &Body= select the send button to send email%0d%0aNOTE: Please do not modify this Email ">Click here to respond for this email </apex:outputlink>
```

Comment: - Thank you. It worked. Is there a possibility to add images in email reply body.

Comment: You can't bind an image with the body.

Comment: So you are saying that in the body we can't append header and footers right.

Comment: I mean we can't pass any HTML tag with body parameter in mailto: